# Core Data NSFetchRequest Sort by Category Method Return Value

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How do I sort my fetched results by a value that is returned by a method in a category of the entity I'm fetching?

In my category, I sum up several values from the entity's to-many relationship, then divide by the number of objects in the relationship, effectively creating an average that I return in my category method as a float value.

Here is my code:

In the Category.h

```m
- (float)smallPenaltyAvg;
```

In the Category.m

```m
- (float)smallPenaltyAvg{
    float smallPenaltyAvg = 0;
    for (Match *mtch in self.matches) {
        smallPenaltyAvg += [mtch.penaltySmall floatValue];
    }

    if ([self.matches count] > 0) {
        smallPenaltyAvg = (float)smallPenaltyAvg/(float)[self.matches count];
    }

    return smallPenaltyAvg;
}
```

And when I call it in the Core Data Table View Controller class that I created...

```m
NSFetchRequest *poolRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Team"];
poolRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"regionalIn.name = %@", _regionalToDisplay];
poolRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"smallPenaltyAvg" ascending:YES]];
```

And I have the `Category.h` file imported on every file previously mentioned outside of the `Category.h` file itself.

It gives me the error of:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath smallPenaltyAvg not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Team id=5>
```

Am I not allowed to do this?

If I am, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this has anything to do with the kind of persistent store.

The trick is to create an appropriate attribute in the managed object model, and mark it as `Transient`. Then override the getter of this attribute to do your calculations.

Now your fetch request should work as expected (although there are some caveats with fetched results controllers).

As for the SQLite problem, when you add the SQLite store with

```m
 - (NSPersistentStore *)addPersistentStoreWithType:(NSString *)storeType 
    configuration:(NSString *)configuration 
    URL:(NSURL *)storeURL 
    options:(NSDictionary *)options 
    error:(NSError **)error
```

just pass `NSSQLiteStoreType` as the `storeType`. The other options are binary and in-memory, so in this sense this is indeed the "default".

Comment: Would you mind doing an example average calculation for a transient property that returns a float value (or an NSNumber with a float value) so I could see the syntax?

Comment: Average calculations are more efficiently done with key paths. `NSNumber *average = [fetchedObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.amount"];`.

Comment: No, I'm talking about average attribute value of Match objects within the "to-many" relationship from Team to Match. ie. A Match object has an attribute called "penaltySmall" that is an NSNumber. I want to retrieve all Match objects within the Team "to-many" relationship and return the average "penaltySmall" float value for the Matches within said Team

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible when using a backing SQLite store.

My suggestion is you persist the average property, and maintain it yourself by overriding the `Match` `setCategory:` property and making the calculation there for every match added.

Comment: So default Core Data storage is SQLite?

Comment: Don't think so. You must specify the type of store you create when adding it to the coordinator.

Comment: My guess is that the backing store is SQLite (guessing that FSA ... is based on `NSManagedDocument`), you can check your file system and see for yourself ...

Comment: The error I'm getting says I'm using NSSQL, not SQLite. I also don't think I put anything in my code that specifies SQLite

Comment: By your error, it is obvious that you do use a backing SQLite store (at least the framework you use).

Comment: Ok, so what would the setCategory: property override look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47535/discussion-between-teamdriven1730-and-dan-shelly)

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my problem was create a new attribute for every average or sum that I needed in the Team object from all of its Match objects' attributes and then created a method in the TeamCategory file that populated those averages and that method was called every time a Match object was inserted into the Team object. It took a while to do, but it works now. If there is a better solution, I'm still open for suggestions.